# cloudfoundry - Settng environment variable -Failed

Tags: cloud-foundry

Trying to set an env variable based off documentation

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md

`$ cf set-env my-application JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT '{tomcat: { context_path: /first-segment/second-segment }}'`

Getting the following:

`FAILED
Incorrect Usage. Requires 'app-name env-name env-value' as arguments`

Answer (score 2):

Raeason for this error is invalid JSON from CF point oif view due to space. It treats space as end of param and start of another input.

You can see from here : 
Below is valid one

**Valid commnand :** 
cf set-env my-application JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT {aaa:{ff:/kk}}

**Invalid command :** due to space in JSON:
cf set-env my-application JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT {aaa: {ff:/kk}}

It has nothing to do with . BOSH installation and warden container make filesystem OS agnostic.

Comment: On Windows it is double quotes! JBP_CONFIG_CONTAINER_SECURITY_PROVIDER "{trust_manager_enabled: false}"

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you using? Those examples assume a Linux variant. The escaping rules for the json string will be different for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The CF CLI team tries to handle all user issues and bug reports through Github issues, would you mind opening one?  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/new